# React Router Component Mounting Twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following:

```
const RoutedApp = ({ signedIn }) => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={routes.HANDLE_SIGN_IN} render={props => <HandleSignIn {...props} />} />
        <PublicRoute exact path={routes.LANDING} signedIn={signedIn} component={LandingContainer} />
        <PrivateRoute exact path={routes.HOME} signedIn={signedIn} component={HomeContainer} />
        <Route component={PageNotFoundContainer} />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

The issue is with the `HandleSignInContainer`.

That component basically just signs the user in and sends them to the home page with `location.push('/home')`;

However, I'm having the issue where `HandleSignInContainer` is mounting twice.

The [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/component) mention that using the Route `render` prop should fix this problem, but then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49055172/react-component-mounting-twice) SO answer mentions that this won't work for components created by an HOC.

Since `HandleSignIn` is wrapped with React Redux's `connect()`, how can I stop this component from mounting twice?

### update 1

Trying to wrap in non-connected component:

```
const WrappedHandleSignInContainer = props => (
  <div>
    <HandleSignInContainer {...props} />
  </div>
);
```

### update 2

Code for the `HandleSignInContainer`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { signInAction } from '../actions/userActions';
import { checkSignInLink } from '../resources/utils';

class HandleSignInContainer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    valid: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    alert('mounted');

    const url = window.location.href;

    if (!checkSignInLink(url)) {
      this.setState({ valid: false });
      return;
    }

    let email = localStorage.getItem('email');
    this.props.signInAction(email, url, this.props.history);
  }

  render() {
    const { valid } = this.state;
    let text;

    if (valid) {
      text = "Please wait, we're signing you in!";
    } else {
      text = "Oops! That doesn't seem to be a valid sign in link.";
    }

    return text;
  }
}

export default connect(null, { signInAction })(HandleSignInContainer);
```

Comment: what if you wrap HandleSignIn with un`connect`ed component ?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk do you mean like above? I've updated the question. The issue persists when I try the above.

Comment: yes. It doesn't help?

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk no, the same issue of the component rendering twice :(

Comment: Could you explain why is it a problem that component is mounting twice? I don't see any antipatterns in this code, so maybe it would be easier to solve your problem directly.

Comment: @TomaszMularczyk Sure, it's a problem because it means the `signInAction` is called twice, which triggers an error the second time. I've updated to show the `HandleSignInContainer` code.

Comment: couldn't you just check if a user has already been signed? relying upon that component will be mounted just once is an error-prone restriction imo.

Comment: What's in `signInAction`?

Comment: I have a different setup that I'm using but facing the same error. Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @Abhas hey, I can't remember how I fixed this, apologies!

Comment: No worries @Colin. Please let me know if you remember it by any chance. I still haven't figured it out.