# React class component renders twice on Chrome only

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I created a project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

```
yarn create react-app example-react-ts --template typescript
```

Then created a simple component:

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface ExampleProps {message: string}

class Example extends React.Component<ExampleProps> {
    render() {
        console.log("render")
        return (<div><p>{this.props.message}</p></div>)
    }
}

export default Example
```

Firefox prints "render" once.

Chrome prints "render" **twice**.

---

If I replace it with a functional component:

```
import * as React from 'react'
interface ExampleProps {message: string}

export const Example = (props: ExampleProps) => {
    console.log("render")
    return (
        <div><p>{props.message}</p></div>
    );
}

export default Example
```

Both Firefox and Chrome print "render" once.

Why?

Comment: It only renders once here in my Chrome: https://codepen.io/Squeegy/pen/yLYEPJx?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) used by default when you create the project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app):

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Removing it solved the problem.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode).

Comment: True, but how did you know that ?

Comment: I didn't until I removed it. I still don't know why it renders twice though.

Comment: It only renders twice in development, not in production. It's supposed to point out some issues with your application