# Why does this component render twice in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, I set a count and let state update when button clicked.
But when I check render times, it renders twice each time I click the button.

https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-forest-yre6y?file=/src/App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const cute = Array(10).fill({});
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);
  console.log(count);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          if (count < 10) setCount(count + 1);
        }}
      >
        add
      </button>
      {cute.map((data, index) => {
        if (index < count) {
          return (
            <div>
              <p>{index}. Luna is cute</p>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I wonder:

1. Why does it work like this?
2. How could I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your app is using `StrictMode`. See your `index.js` file - your app is wrapped between a `<React.StrictMode>` element.

Using `StrictMode` will cause your app to render twice, but only in development mode. Creating an app with `create-react-app` will enable strict mode by default.

Here are the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) for strict mode.

The solution is just to remove `<React.StrictMode>`, but that will also disable some of its advantages, so if it doesn't bother you, I'd just leave it as is, knowing it won't render like that in production.

See this related question for more details: [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously that re-rendering thing is definitely not a bug, or something related with the library's render mechanism. On the contrary it is a debugging mechanism provided by React

refer this blog https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/
you'll get better understanding .

you can disable strictmode refer this sandbox link.it'll only render once .

https://codesandbox.io/s/snowy-violet-eo70o?file=/src/index.js