# Why does the render function in react is called twice when using the component strategy?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I am new to react and what to understand why the console.log is called twice when inside of the render function ?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log("Prints twice in console");
    return (
      <div className="App">

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Where as if i dont extend from component and use function instead the console prints only once

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
function App() {
  console.log("prints once");
  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I might add this is not the best way to debug an app. The React itself might rerender your component whenever it see it fit

Comment: In this article somebody talks in depth about the double rendering: https://mariosfakiolas.com/blog/my-react-components-render-twice-and-drive-me-crazy/

Comment: thanks dejoma - the article helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your **index.js** in the **./src** directory. I think it renders the **App component** in

```
<React.StrictMode>
```

Remove it and it will stop rendering the function twice.

Also you can check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)