# Promises are running twice in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple promise and when I call then on it, the promise is running twice.

```js
import React from 'react'

function App() {

  let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve("hello")
  })

  promise.then(function (res) {
    console.log(res)
  })
  return (
    <>
      Hello
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

When I visit localhost:3000, and open debugger it shows "hello" printed twice. I am not able to understand what is going on. Please help

Comment: Because one time you `console.log(res)` which logs hello and one time you explicitly `console.log('hello')` which logs it a second time.

Comment: ?? There are two separate calls to `console.log("hello")` in the code you posted.

Comment: @Pointy  I put second console.log by mistake in the question. Even without that it is printing "hello" twice. Now I have edited the question, can you help me now? It will be very helpful.

Comment: [React.StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) makes your code execute twice while in development mode to ensure you dont have state issues. Generally speaking, you should never call a Promise in a functional component without safe-guarding it with setState as it will be called/evaluated on every render

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

Comment: Thanks guys, now my problem is solved!!!!!! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), it's likely that your `App` is wrapped with [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) which causes an additional render of your `App`. Check your app's `index.js`.