# How to avoid "HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode" in the AudioContext Interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, audiocontext, visualizer

I've made an audio visualizer in React with the AudioContext interface and I want the user able to enable and disable it. 
The visualizer works fine and I can disable it as well (I just remove the vis component)

However, when I want to enable it again, it tells me : *"InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'AudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode."* 
I suppose that I can't have 2 ElementSources on a audio element at the same time. But I can't manage to work around this error. 
I've tried to return **audiocontext.close()** in my useEffect hook so I can create a new *MediaElementSource* then (not sure if it works this way) but it doesn't change anything. 
Maybe there is a property on the audio element that can tell me if there is already a MediaElementSource ? (I didn't find anything)

Or maybe the AudioContext interface is a bit too hard for me since I'm only a beginner in React and I've just copy paste an existing visualizer...

Thanks for the help!

Here is some code from my visualizer component :

```js
useEffect(() => {
  var context = new AudioContext(); //Some visualiser stuff
  var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);// The error is here
  src.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
  var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
  src.connect(analyser);
  analyser.connect(context.destination);
  analyser.fftSize = 1024;

  // Some canvas stuff here
  //

  return () => {
    context.close() // doesn't work ?
  };
}, [somedeps]);

return  <canvas>...</canvas>
```

Comment: For me it was due to React Strict mode -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem .

according to error message you don't need dependency in useEffect (Because `src` only needs to be defined once otherwise you will get an error).

instead save `src` into state and use two `useEffect` to access `src` changes when audio changes :

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

  const [source, setSource] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
      const ctx = new AudioContext();
      
      //declare source just once
      const src = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      setSource(src);
      
      //connect analayser to source
      const analayser = ctx.createAnalyser();
      src.connect(analayser);
      analayser.connect(ctx.destination);
    }
  }, []);
  
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(source);
    //result : MediaElementAudioSourceNode {mediaElement: audio, context: AudioContext, numberOfInputs: 0, numberOfOutputs: 1, channelCount: 2, …}
    
  }, [//use dependency here]);
```

Comment: React.StrictMode makes the component render twice which creates the same error as the HTMLMediaElement gets connected in the first render. Am wondering, is the a way to disconnect the HTMLMediaElement from the previous MediaElementSourceNode so that it can get a fresh reconnection?

Comment: You can remove the window !== undefined check inside useEffect. If useEffect on [] triggers, window is guaranteed to be defined.