# What is the difference between React running in development and production?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am writing a React+react-query application today and I am running into a problem when I switched from development mode to production mode.

Production mode is a mix of running `npm run build` and serving those HTML/JavaScript/CSS files inside a serve (maybe using `npx serve dist`). Development mode is just running `npm run dev` (or `npm start` if using CRA).

This is the code:

```
const useMyQuery = () =>
  useQuery(
    ["myAwesomeData"],
    async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`http://http.us/500`);
      return data;
    },
    { placeholderData: { myAwesomeProperty: [] } }
  );

const App = () => {
  const { isError } = useMyQuery();
  return isError ? <div>Error</div> : <Child />;
};

const Child = () => {
  const { data } = useMyQuery();
  return (
    <pre>
      <code>{JSON.stringify(data.myAwesomeProperty)}</code>
    </pre>
  );
};
```

For the sake of simplicity, I omitted `QueryClientProvider` and its `client`. Also `placeholderData` is being used as a loading state, which allows `Child` to be properly rendered while real data is loading.

The most important part here is `data.myAwesomeProperty` AFTER the loading state - which throws an error ONLY when running in production. The error produced is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'myAwesomeProperty' of undefined
```

When running on development, the `<div>Error</div>` appears as expected.

My main concern here is NOT solve the problem (as I could simply add a `if` statement on `Child` component to prevent accessing `data.myAwesomeProperty`).

Instead, I would like to know why there is a difference between development's and production's behavior? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Is there a reason you're quoting all this text? It kinda looks like it's just your own text, just... use regular text? (and use code fences, or code indentation, for that TypeError)

Answer (score 2):

The `dev` and `prod` version of React has quite a bit difference. But the main one can be the speed here. In general the `prod` version is a lot more performant.

Based on the way you write, there's no way you should expect a valid `myAwesomeProperty`. So in the prod, you get the error right away.

In the `dev`, maybe things slow down, when you get the `Child`, the API already finishes.

NOTE: list coupe of dev/prod difference.

- profiler enabled to collect time info
- debug logger, adds quite a bit name and check
- check hooks count and order match
- strict mode adds bunch of stuff, https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

I also notice in the strict mode, things can be rendered twice, [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

This might answer if you don't get an error, since the double render actually happened in one update (not two updates).