# What is the difference between initialization a useState inside a useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

```
const [state, set_state] = useState(1);
```

vs

```
const [state, set_state] = useState();
useEffect(() => {
  set_state(1);
}, [])
```

Is there any real difference between the two in terms of in what cycle the update actually happens? Does using a `useEffect` cause an additional cycle, etc?

Comment: Yes it does cause another rerender.

Comment: the latter will cause the state to be initialized only when the component is mounted, and with the `set_state` inside it, it will cause a second render everytime. So, the former is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for the [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) functional argument:

> **Lazy initial state**
>
> The `initialState` argument is the state used during the initial render. In subsequent renders, it is disregarded. If the initial state is the result of an expensive computation, you may provide a function instead, which will be executed only on the initial render:
>
> ```js
> const [state, setState] = useState(() => {
>   const initialState = someExpensiveComputation(props);
>   return initialState;
> });
> ```

But rather than just supply a link, let's examine the different behaviors of the code you showed (in addition to the lazy initial state functional argument).

> A note about the code examples below:
>
> They use a custom helper hook to record information about when component renders occur and when state values are updated. The outputs are serialized as [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON), so when a state value is [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined), it is represented as [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/null) in the JSON (because `undefined` is not a valid JSON type). Because of the restrictions of Stack Overflow's code snippet mechanism, there's a lot of repeated boilerplate — the code in focus is in the body of the `App` function.

### Creating state initialized with a value:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(1);
```

In this case, the state is initialized once and never updated. The component is rendered one time:

```html
<style>.json { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.15); font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const { useCallback, useRef, useState } = React;

function VisualJson ({ data }) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(
    data,
    // undefined doesn't serialize, so null is used as a substitute:
    (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value,
    2,
  );
  return (<pre className="json"><code>{ json }</code></pre>);
}

function useComponentUpdateMeta (state) {
  const ref = useRef({
    updates: [],
    get totalRenders () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "render").length;
    },
    get totalStateUpdates () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "state").length;
    },
  });

  ref.current.updates.push({ type: "render", time: performance.now(), state });

  const recordStateUpdate = useCallback(state => {
    ref.current.updates.push({ type: "state", time: performance.now(), state });
  }, [ref]);

  return [ref.current, recordStateUpdate];
}

function App () {
  const [state, setState] = useState(1);

  const [updateMeta, recordStateUpdate] = useComponentUpdateMeta(state);

  return (<VisualJson data={ updateMeta } />);
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

### Creating state uninitialized, then updating in a `useEffect` callback:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  setState(1);
}, []);
```

In this case, the state is initialized with an implicit `undefined` value and the component is rendered. Then the `useEffect` hook's callback function is invoked and the state is updated, causing the component to render a second time:

```html
<style>.json { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.15); font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

function VisualJson ({ data }) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(
    data,
    // undefined doesn't serialize, so null is used as a substitute:
    (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value,
    2,
  );
  return (<pre className="json"><code>{ json }</code></pre>);
}

function useComponentUpdateMeta (state) {
  const ref = useRef({
    updates: [],
    get totalRenders () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "render").length;
    },
    get totalStateUpdates () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "state").length;
    },
  });

  ref.current.updates.push({ type: "render", time: performance.now(), state });

  const recordStateUpdate = useCallback(state => {
    ref.current.updates.push({ type: "state", time: performance.now(), state });
  }, [ref]);

  return [ref.current, recordStateUpdate];
}

function App () {
  const [state, setState] = useState();

  const [updateMeta, recordStateUpdate] = useComponentUpdateMeta(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(1);
    recordStateUpdate(1);
  }, []);

  return (<VisualJson data={ updateMeta } />);
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

### Creating state initialized with a lazily-invoked function:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(() => 1);
```

Similar to the first example: in this case, the state is initialized once (using a function whose return value becomes the initial state value) and never updated. The component is rendered one time:

```html
<style>.json { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.15); font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const { useCallback, useRef, useState } = React;

function VisualJson ({ data }) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(
    data,
    // undefined doesn't serialize, so null is used as a substitute:
    (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value,
    2,
  );
  return (<pre className="json"><code>{ json }</code></pre>);
}

function useComponentUpdateMeta (state) {
  const ref = useRef({
    updates: [],
    get totalRenders () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "render").length;
    },
    get totalStateUpdates () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "state").length;
    },
  });

  ref.current.updates.push({ type: "render", time: performance.now(), state });

  const recordStateUpdate = useCallback(state => {
    ref.current.updates.push({ type: "state", time: performance.now(), state });
  }, [ref]);

  return [ref.current, recordStateUpdate];
}

function App () {
  const [state, setState] = useState(() => 1);

  const [updateMeta, recordStateUpdate] = useComponentUpdateMeta(state);

  return (<VisualJson data={ updateMeta } />);
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

reactRoot.render(<App />);

</script>
```

---

One more consideration is this: when using [Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) in development, React will unmount and re-mount your entire app's tree of nodes, effectively causing an extra render.

> References:
>
> - [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61254372/438273)
> - [What is the difference between React running in development and production?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69080747/438273)

```html
<style>.json { background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 50%, 0.15); font-family: monospace; font-size: 1rem; padding: 0.5rem; }</style>
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.20.12/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="env,react">

const { StrictMode, useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

function VisualJson ({ data }) {
  const json = JSON.stringify(
    data,
    // undefined doesn't serialize, so null is used as a substitute:
    (_key, value) => typeof value === "undefined" ? null : value,
    2,
  );
  return (<pre className="json"><code>{ json }</code></pre>);
}

function useComponentUpdateMeta (state) {
  const ref = useRef({
    updates: [],
    get totalRenders () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "render").length;
    },
    get totalStateUpdates () {
      return this.updates.filter(u => u.type === "state").length;
    },
  });

  ref.current.updates.push({ type: "render", time: performance.now(), state });

  const recordStateUpdate = useCallback(state => {
    ref.current.updates.push({ type: "state", time: performance.now(), state });
  }, [ref]);

  return [ref.current, recordStateUpdate];
}

function App () {
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const [updateMeta, recordStateUpdate] = useComponentUpdateMeta(state);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(1);
    recordStateUpdate(1);
  }, []);

  return (<VisualJson data={ updateMeta } />);
}

const reactRoot = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

reactRoot.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```