# React console.log runs once in render, but side effect occurs twice? StrictMode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know this is occurring due to React.StrictMode, but am very confused exactly how this behavior is occurring.

Basically, I have a very simple component, that logs each time it renders, and also increments a global counter when it does so

```js
let logCount = 0;

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const incrementCount = React.useCallback(() => setCount(count + 1), [count]);

  console.log(logCount++, Math.random());

  return (
    <div>
      {count}
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>rerender me!</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>, 
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Each time the component rerenders, I will see only a single console.log, but logCount will have incremented **twice**. If I turn off React.StrictMode, it will only have incremented a single time.

I'm mostly just curious if react has some special logic to ensure console.log statements and the like are only executed a single time, even in strict mode? If not, then I'm even more curious what I'm missing here. I added a Math.random() call as a sanity check.

Comment: Looks like this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/10431732

Comment: I'm getting two logs for each click

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I also get 2 logs for each click within the stack overflow snippet, but only one log when I open the app normally in chrome. Not sure what's happening but it's probably not particularly important