# React useEffect making multiple Requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I have yet another React useEffect question.
I've read a lot of responses and I've also started from a scratch example but I still don't understand why my app makes 2 requests instead of 1.

I've initially thought it has something to do with re-rendering of components because I have a loading state and so on, but I've dumbed everything down and I still get this:

Test.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const Test = () => {
    //let data = { title: "Waiting for Data" };
    //const [todo, setTodo] = useState(data);
    //const [isData, setData] = useState(false);
    //const [isFetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // called after the first render
      async function fetchData() {
        console.log(
          " ----------- cause the re-render ----------- 2 ",
          "setFetching = true"
        );
        //setFetching(true); // causing re-render - 2
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"
        );
        console.log("response = ", response);
        //let data = await response.json();
        console.log(" ----------- cause the re-render ----------- 3 ", "setTodo");
        //setTodo(data); //updt state
        console.log(
          " ----------- cause the re-render ----------- 4 ",
          "setFetching = false"
        );
        //setFetching(false);
        console.log(" ----------- cause the re-render ----------- 5 ", "setData");
        //setData(true);
        //console.log("Data = ", data);
      }
      fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    return(
        <>
        <p>hey !</p>
        </>
    )

}

export default Test
```

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import Test from './components/Auth/Test';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Test />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

As you can see I've commented out everything, I've only left the console.logs and I got this result:

[image]
[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "kindergarden-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.29",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Do you guys have any ideas or guidance on how I can make this a single call ?
Thanks !

Comment: This is related to React's strict mode rendering components twice (while in development mode), read this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode/61897567#61897567

Comment: Wow... I would never have taught about it. Thank you very much !