# Memoization of custom useLocalStorage hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usememo

I'm creating a react app that has a few states that I want to read/save to localStorage.
I've created a `useLocalStorage` hook, and it's working, but I'm concerned that I'm reading from local storage every time the `App` component re-renders.

I'd appreciate if someone could let me know if this is the case. I'd also appreciate any hints on if/how I could use `useMemo` or `useCallback` to improve this code.

**App.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocalStorage } from "../useLocalStorage";

export default function App() {

  const [saved1, setSaved1] = useLocalStorage("saved1", "The first test");
  const [saved2, setSaved2] = useLocalStorage("saved2", "The second test");

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{saved1}</p>
      <input type="text" value={saved1} onChange={(e) => setSaved1(e.target.value)} />
      <p>{saved2}</p>
      <input type="text" value={saved2} onChange={(e) => setSaved2(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**useLocalStorage.js**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useLocalStorage = (key, defaultValue) => {
  console.log("Called useLocalStorage");
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    try {
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      return item ? parseJSON(item) : defaultValue;
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(`Error reading localStorage key “${key}”:`, error); 
      return defaultValue;
    }
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Called useEffect");
    try {
      const newValue = value instanceof Function ? value(value) : value;
      window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error); 
    }
  }, [key, value]);
  return [value, setValue];
};

// Wrapper to help handle undefined with JSON.parse
function parseJSON(value) {
  try {
    return value === "undefined" ? undefined : JSON.parse(value ?? "");
  } catch {
    console.log("parsing error on", { value });
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

There are other states in `App` that I've left out for clarity. At the moment I'm getting `Called useLocalStorage` console logged twice every time any of these states changes, e.g. toggling dark theme gives me the two console logs.

Comment: Does this happen in production?

Comment: @ksav I haven't checked. Out of curiosity, why do you ask?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode/61897567#61897567

Comment: So build your app in production mode, (or turn off strict mode) and see if you are still getting `Called useLocalStorage` console logged twice

Comment: Interesting. I hadn't even considered something like this. Thanks for this information @ksav!