# Why is my API request being called 4 times?

Tags: reactjs, api, request

I'm working on a project that makes an api request, but my request is being called 4 times, why is this happening?

````
const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {

    getMovies(FEATURED_API)
    
    if (searchTerm) {
      getMovies(SEARCH_API + searchTerm);
    } else{
      getMovies(FEATURED_API)
    }

  }, [searchTerm])


  const getMovies = (API) => {
    fetch(API)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      setMovies(data.results)
    })
  }

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value)
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling the `getMovies(FEATURED_API)` twice on mount (one *outside the if cause* and the other in the *else*).

```
useEffect(() => {

 getMovies(FEATURED_API) // first call

 if (searchTerm) {
   getMovies(SEARCH_API + searchTerm);
 } else{
  getMovies(FEATURED_API) // second call because searchTerm is an empty string
 }
}, [searchTerm])
```

And the other two calls are probably because you have `StrictMode` enabled (it is enabled as default with `create-react-app`) and you haven't noticed it. `StrictMode` mounts your component twice in development mode to help you detect problems in your code in an easier way.

You can check [this post comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/12222861) with a more descriptive concept of what StrictMode does.