# socket.io post message twice (react)

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

sometimes its post 3-4 times.
probably its about rendering. i moved init function from container.jsx to app.jsx not worked.
tried to delete cache. not worked
as you can see from console log. is chatlist rendered twice? or something like that
using socket.broadcast.emit on backend. not working

[image]

client code

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

export const init = () => {
    console.log("Connecting...");
    socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {
        transports: ["websocket"],
    });
    socket.on("connect", () => console.log("Connected!"));
};

export const sendMessage = (message) => {
    if (socket) {
        socket.emit("new-message", message);
    }
};

export const onNewMessage = (callback) => {
    if (!socket) return;
    socket.on("receive-message", (message) => {
        callback(message);
        console.log("Received message: ", message);
    });
};
```

server code

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const cors = require("cors");

const Messages = require("./lib/Messages");

app.use(cors());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.end("Merhaba Socket.IO");
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    console.log("a user connected");

    Messages.list((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit("message-list", data);
    });

    socket.on("new-message", (message) => {
        console.log(message);
        Messages.upsert({ message });

        socket.broadcast.emit("receive-message", message);
    });

    socket.on("disconnect", () => console.log("a user disconnected"));
});

http.listen(process.env.PORT || "3000", () => {
    console.log("listening on *:3000");
});
```

chatlist.jsx

```
import { useChat } from "../context/ChatContext";
import styles from "./style.module.css";
import ChatItem from "./ChatItem";

export default function ChatList() {
    const { messages } = useChat();
    console.log(messages);
    return (
        <div className={styles.chatlist}>
            <div>
                {messages.map((item, key) => (
                    console.log("Message: ",item),
                    <ChatItem key={key} value={item} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: A mesaage that you send is showed mulltiple times?

Comment: yes, it is @AngelHdz

Comment: If the message is sent but showed multiple times in the user that received, try ro remove the listeners,  like:  `"socket.removeAllListeners("receive-message")` and then `socket.on("receive-message",...`

Comment: You are probably running in strict mode. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Answer (score 0):

its because of the useEffect bug in last version of react

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33062572)

Answer (score 0):

```
useMemo(() => {
socket.on('receiveMessage', (payload: any) => {
  setChatMsg((pre: any) => [...pre, payload]);
})},[socket]);
```

you can use useMemo