# React: How to avoid duplication in a state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-state

I am making MERN social media app.

I want to show all the friends of the current user in a list in SideBar.jsx .

Home.jsx (parent of Sidebar.jsx)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Person } from "@material-ui/icons";
import Topbar from "../../components/topbar/Topbar";
import Sidebar from "../../components/sidebar/Sidebar";
import Feed from "../../components/feed/Feed";
import Rightbar from "../../components/rightbar/Rightbar";
import "./home.css";
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="homeContainer">
        <Sidebar />
        <Feed />
        <Rightbar />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

SideBar.jsx

```
import "./sidebar.css";
import React, { Component, useContext, useState } from "react";
...
import { axiosInstance } from "../../config";

export default function Sidebar() {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [followings, setFollowings] = useState([]);
  const followingsList = user.followings;
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFollowings = async () => {
      followingsList.map(async (id) => {
        try {
          const theUser = await axiosInstance.get(`/users?userId=${id}`);
          if (followings.includes(theUser.data)) {
          } else {
            setFollowings((prev) => [...prev, theUser.data]);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }

      });
    };
    fetchFollowings();
  }, [user]);
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
  .....
        <ul className="sidebarFriendList">
          {followings.map((u) => (
            <CloseFriend key={u._id} user={u} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For example, in this case, in the state "followings", there are 2 user objects.

So, the line

```
 followings.map((u) => (...
```

should only show 2 entries.

However, the result is below.

[image]

As you can see, it is showing each friend twice.
I tired to check if a user object already exists in followings by doing

```
 if (followings.includes(theUser.data)) {
          } else {
            setFollowings((prev) => [...prev, theUser.data]);
          }
```

But this is not working.

How can I make sure that it only shows each user once?

I want it to be like this
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you

Comment: Add some debugging console logs, one for `u` at the rendering, one in the state setting call. Even try saving the new state array to a variable in  `setFollowings` and log it.

Comment: When you have 3 followings every follower will be displayed three times right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because it seems that your `useEffect` method is being fired two times (probably because you are using `React.StrictMode`) and you are setting the state inside the `.map` method (that is not good because you trigger a new render each time you call the `setState`).

What I would recommend you to do, is to remove the `setState` from the `.map` method and just set the new state after you format your data. So it would be something like this:

```
const newFollowings = followingsList.map(async (id) => {
  try {
    const theUser = await axiosInstance.get(`/users?userId=${id}`);
    return theUser.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

setFollowings(newFollowings);
```

Probably you would have to add a filtering to the array in case there are some errors (because on errors the mapped value would be `undefined`):

```
.filter(data => data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I'm not really familiar with React.StrictMode, but the takeAway is that I should not setState in .map method, since it'll trigger re-rendering while it's doing the map method, that is why im seeing this behavior of map method, is it pretty correct?

Comment: Well, in part. You were seeing the behavior of duplicate values because of the `(prev) => [...prev, theUser.data]` declaration. There, you were retrieving the previous state values and adding new values (when triggering the `useEffect` twice, you were adding that extra two values to your state). With the current answer approach, you are setting a completely new state, so if the `useEffect` triggers twice we are just overriding the previous values. For a reference of `React.StrictMode` (not sure if this is your case) you can check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/12222861

Answer (score 1):

When you are using the `.map` function with `async/await` `Promise.all` usually always does the trick. Instead of pushing the state on every iteration you collect the followers list and set the state when all your fetching is done. I did not test it yet, but I hope it works.

```js
const followingsList = user.followings;

useEffect(() => {
    const fetchFollowings = async () => {
      const list = await Promise.all(followingsList.map(async (id) => (
        await axios.get('/user?userId=' + id);
      )));
      
      setFollowers(list);
    };
    fetchFollowings();
  }, [user]);
```

Note: let me know if it works, if not I'll do a little sandbox on my own