# How do I run redux -toolkit only once in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to execute a dispatch called loadMe once when rendering for the first time with useEffect in the About component.

However, when the screen is refreshed, the dispatch is executed 4 times. Like the picture blow

[image]

How can I run it only once?

this is my code

About.tsx

const About = () => {

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

useEffect( () => {
    const loadMy = async()=> {
    dispatch(loadMe());
    }
    loadMy();

},[]);

return (
    <>
    <div>About page</div>
    </>
);
};

export default About;
```

Action.tsx

```
export const loadMe = createAsyncThunk(
    '/loadMe',
    async ( data, {rejectWithValue}) => {
      try {
        const userId = await localStorage.getItem('UserId');
        return userId;  
      } catch (error: any) {
          console.error(error);
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data);
      }
    },
  );
```

Comment: Could the problem be related to strict mode?

Comment: @AndrewHulterstrom what does mean?

Comment: Strict mode causes renders to happen twice. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/15351640

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called 4 times because of async and the way react works under the hood.

**React Strict Mode**

The way react works in development mode is that it runs in strict mode by default. In strict mode all components are rendered twice to aid developer in error checking.
So paired with async this makes 4 dispatches in total

**Async**

With Async functions, they are called initially and return a promise which dispatches the first 2 times causing a render, when the promise is resolved, another re-render happens causing the dispatch to be made again 2 times.

Comment: so in this case what happens when I make an async post request, does that mean it till be posted twice. the fact that dispatch will be called twice ?