# React hooks set state being called multiples times when updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an app like this

```
function App(){
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState(
        {
            questions: []
        }
    )

    const addToQuestion = (questionObject) =>{

        setAppState((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, questions: [...prevState.questions, questionObject]}
        })

    }

    let removeFromQuestionArray = () => {
        setAppState((prevState) => {
            let a = prevState.questions
            a.pop()
            return {...prevState, questions: a}
        })
    }

    const onBackButtonClicked = () => {
        removeFromQuestionArray()
    }
}
```

But when I call `removeFromQuestionsArray()` the setAppState works unpredictably. It sometimes removes all the items in the array even though I'm only popping the last item in the array. What could be causing this. I just want to remove the last item from the array, how can I go about this without having issues?

Comment: Try removing Strict Mode tags in index.js and see what happens.

Comment: This looks like it's working now and it'ss the only thing that has worked so far, no more random updates. Is there a solution that wouldn't require the removal of the strict mode tags? I will be loosing some helpful warning messages without it.

Comment: It works with strict mode too, check my answer

Comment: Can you make a Code Sandbox that shows the unpredictable behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine.

Posting this as an answer to show the snippet:

Note: I edited the `addToQuestions` function to make it work for the example, but I didn't touch `removeFromQuestionsArray`

```js
const { useState, useRef } = React

function App(){
    const [appState, setAppState] = useState(
        {
            questions: [
              'What is Love',
              'Whats the meaning of life',
              'Whats the answer to this question'
            ]
        }
    )
    
    const input = useRef();

    const addToQuestion = () =>{
        let question = input.current.value;
        setAppState((prevState) => {
            return {...prevState, questions: [...prevState.questions, question]}
        })
        input.current.value = '';
        input.current.focus();

    }

    let removeFromQuestionArray = () => {
        setAppState((prevState) => {
            let a = prevState.questions
            a.pop()
            return {...prevState, questions: a}
        })
    }
  return (
  <div>
    {appState.questions.map(question => <li>{question}</li>)}
    <input ref={input}></input>
    <button onClick={addToQuestion}>Add Question</button>
    <button onClick={removeFromQuestionArray}>Remove</button>
  </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
,
  root
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: In addToQuestion the line input.current.value throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value').

Comment: Are you getting that error when running it from the snippet?

Comment: No, its when I have it in my IDE.

Comment: Make sure you import `useRef` even though that'd give a different error if you hadn't. And make sure you set the `ref` property of the input element to `input` which is declared after the state: `<input ref={input}></input>`

Comment: Your version works in the code snippet but you haven't changed anything in the removeQuestionsFromArray that would cause the state update to not be made multiple times undesirably.

Comment: Exactly, to show that the original version in your question doesn't act undesirably.

Comment: I'm not sure how useRef addresses the issue, could you pls fill me in? I know its used to persist data between renders but I'm not much informed on it.

Comment: Its weird because when I run it and inspect the state in chrome using the React Developer Tools the items in the array get removed undesirably and logging to the console shows multiple calls to the setAppState is made causing more than one item to be removed from the array.

Comment: Try to recreate the issue in this [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/index.js) and post it here or in the question, I'd be happy to look at it.

Comment: Maybe this is a clue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/4268050

I was just reading react invokes the App Component twice but only in dev mode to find problems with the code if there are any when StrictMode is on.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem because `setAppState` doesn't run when the component re-renders. Do you have any effect hooks (`useEffect`) anywhere else in the ocmponenet?

Comment: No I've not got any effect hooks at all.

Comment: Hmmm, try recreating the issue in the sandbox, it'll help debug it