# Why is my React app not pushing all elements to an array state?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a table that maps through a state that is set to an array of users. The users are retrieved from a server and database, however, I'm only getting one user added to the state when there are two total.

This is how I'm adding users to the state:

```js
const [customerAccounts, setCustomerAccounts] = useState([]);

for(let i = 0; i < res.data.customerAccounts.length; i++) {
  setCustomerAccounts([...customerAccounts, res.data.customerAccounts[i]]);
}
```

When I log each index of `res.data.customerAccounts` I get both accounts logged, but only one is displayed in the table, and when I log the state with a button I also only see one, and it's always the second one (index 1, not 0). What could be the reason for this?

Comment: This would be much cleaner as simply `setCustomerAccounts((prev) => prev.concat(res.data.customerAccounts))`

Comment: Or "setCustomerAccounts([...customerAccounts, ...res.data.customerAccounts]);"

Comment: @JeffreyRam not recommended. Updating state based on the current value should use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

Comment: @Phil That works in getting all users in the table, but it renders users twice. Any way to run the hook once?

Comment: If you don't want to build up your array every time the code above runs, then simply use `setCustomerAccounts(res.data.customerAccounts)`. I'm guessing you've got the above in an effect hook and it's [running twice due to strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61254372/283366)