# In React Js, I want to render component only if props updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render the component if its props are updated others don't need to render. But in my code, I can see it's rendering with unexpected behavior.

React Version 17.X.X

See below code

index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

app.js file

```
import React, { useState, useCallback} from 'react'
import ListItem from './ListItem'
function App() {
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  
  const increase = useCallback(() => setCounter(prevState => prevState + 1), counter); 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ListItem itemList={itemList} addItem={(val) => setItemList(prev => [...prev,val])}/>
      <button onClick={increase}> Increment Count </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ListItem.js

```
import React, {memo} from 'react';
const ListItem = memo(props) => {
 console.log('listItem render...');
 return (
  <div>{props.itemList.map((c) => <span>{c}</span>)}</div>
  <button onClick={() => props.addItem(props.itemList.length + 1)}>+ Add Item</button>
 )
}

export default ListItem;
```

You can see my code and now I want to understand how I can avoid unexpected rendering. Because useCallback using I can avoid re-initiation of that method. but the ListItem component if you can see it's rendering Even if you are adding counter value.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When does the component render now?

Comment: You should pass an array to `useCallback` dependencies: `useCallback(..., [counter])`

Comment: Thanks @Enve it's by mistake I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `addItem` has a method type prop so you need to create a `useCallback()` for that method which you have passed as a prop in `addItem`. This will work for you:

```
const onAddItem = useCallback((val) => {
  setItemList(prev => [...prev,val]);
}, [itemList]);

<ListItem itemList={itemList} addItem={onAddItem}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, @ankit for your answer. but could you please tell why it's rendering component two time when adding item.

Comment: itemList dep is redundant...

@VjyV on your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

btw your ListItem currently holds logic which would be much cleaner if you extract it on a parent level. i.e. when you click the "Add" button just invoke .props.onAdd and implement your onAdd logic in the parent.