# Why is React calling some of my App's functions multiple times?

Tags: reactjs

I was debugging a React app and noticed that some of my functions were called multiple times in a way I could not explain.

I initially thought it was some sort of "developer feature" and tried to run a build, and all I could see if that the APIs that should not be called were called once instead of twice:

```js
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const cities = ["montreal", "london", "shanghai"];

  const [city, setCity] = useState(cities[0]);

  const getCityParameter = useCallback(
    (newCity) => {
      console.log("[1] getCityParameter");
      console.log(`newCity: ${newCity}`);
      console.log(`city: ${city}`);
      return (newCity ?? city).toUpperCase();
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [city]
  );
  const [cityParameter, setCityParameter] = useState(getCityParameter());

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      const newCity = event?.target.value;
      console.log("handleCityChange");
      console.log(`newCity: ${newCity}`);
      if (newCity !== undefined) {
        setCity(newCity);
      }
      const newCityParameter = getCityParameter(newCity);
      setCityParameter(newCityParameter);
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [city]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <select onChange={handleChange} value={city}>
        {cities.map((city) => {
          return (
            <option value={city} key={city}>
              {city}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <div>{cityParameter}</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I created this code sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-butterfly-brh7fk?file=/src/App.js

If you clear the console log, and change the dropdown, you will notice that `getCityParameter` is called 3 times when I would expect it to be called once.

This seems to be a pretty low-level React feature and I apologize for the "not-so-small" example - this is the best I could come up with to reproduce the behavior.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: I am curious why you are setting a useState var to a function instead of a value then using a useEffect to populate and update that value?

Comment: @Chris OP's approach is one I like to follow too - it feels less clunky to me when I can save the new state in a variable and use that variable instead of an additional `useEffect` (which may not be close, code-distance wise, to the location of the state setter call - making the flow harder to understand at a glance). Matter of opinion, I guess.

Comment: :) Nothing but respect! I just had never seen an approach like this  one yet, so was just curious of the value. Thank you for explaining @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the change handler, first:

```
const newCityParameter = getCityParameter(newCity);
```

So that's one call for `getCityParameter`. Then, the component re-renders because the state setter was called. This:

```
const [cityParameter, setCityParameter] = useState(getCityParameter());
```

is like doing

```
const result = getCityParameter();
const [cityParameter, setCityParameter] = useState(result);
```

The function gets called again every time the component renders, so you see it again. Finally, [because you're in strict mode:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61254372)

```
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

The app re-renders a second time, so `getCityParameter` runs again, making a total of 3 times that it's been called when the dropdown is changed.

The initial state value is only used when the component mounts, of course - which means that calling a function every time the component renders when not needed might be seen as unnecessary or confusing. If you wanted `getCityParameter` to not be called on re-renders, and to only be called on mount in order to determine the initial state value, [use the functional version of `useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state). Change

```
const [cityParameter, setCityParameter] = useState(getCityParameter());
```

to

```
const [cityParameter, setCityParameter] = useState(getCityParameter);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you clear the console, and only do 1 dropdown change, normally `handleChange` is called - I am not sure I understand why `getCityParameter` would be called multiple times in this scenario?

Comment: When the change is handled, you call a state setter. When the state setter is called, the component re-renders. When the component re-renders, `getCityParameter` is called. Because you're in strict mode, the component re-renders twice - adding up to 3, like it says in the answer

Comment: I think the part I'm having difficulty following is why is `getCityParameter` called during re-rederring. Because it's only supposed to be called during the initial `useState` (on page load) and once during `handleChange`

Comment: `... useState(getCityParameter())` is equivalent to `const result = getCityParameter(); ...useState(result)` - parentheses after a function name invokes the function. So every time the component re-renders, the function is invoked. Use lazy initialization (see link in answer) if you only want to call the function the first time the component renders.

Comment: Ah! super, thanks now it clarifies - I thought that `useState` was only used at page load but it's because I was using it with a function call.