# useState fires multiples times while adding prevState

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to get Event value and then add that value to an new Array, but useState value fires multiple time, any solution?

```
const [receivedItems, setReceivedItems] = useState([]);
const [newItems, setNewItems] = useState([]);

//Get selected value
const handleSelected = (e) => {
  setReceivedItems(e);
};

useEffect(() => {
  setNewItems((prevState) => [...prevState, receivedItems]);
}, [receivedItems]);
```

Result in:

```
// first render // newItem
// second render // 2 newItem
```

Answer (score 1):

The `useEffect` hook always runs once more in the begining for the initial render. In your case it runs: **one** - for the initial render, **two** - for the actual state update.

**But**: if you see that the useEffect is **always** called twice and not just for the first render - then it's probably because you have `React.StrictMode` in your index.js. See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode).

And also change this line:

```
  setNewItems((prevState) => [...prevState, receivedItems]);
```

To this:

```
setNewItems((prevState) => [...prevState, ...receivedItems]);
```

You need to extract the elements from the `receivedItems` array in order to add them correctly.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still same

Comment: What do you mean still same? That's how it's supposed to be. For the first time the component loads the `useEffect` will run twice. If you have an issue that it **always** fires twice - then that because of the `<React.StrictMode/>` in your index.js, so if you remove it, it won't be called twice for each render **except** the first one. I edited the answer to inculde this note there.

Comment: I'm using React Native