# API calls runs twice on modal popup

Tags: reactjs

```
    I am using "react": "^17.0.2",
    
    my API call runs twice when I use useEffect on a modal popup
    
     useEffect(() => {
            console.log('kbghjdfhgd');
        }, []);
    
    when I used it in modal pop up it ran twice but if I used it in an app.js it ran once only
```

I am new to react not sure what went wrong in it.

Comment: Seems like the StrictMode thing, to help finding accidental impurities in dev mode React calls component function twice

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running your project in `strict mode`.
You can do this by checking the `render()` method in `index.tsx`.

If you don't know what 'strict mode' is here's what the React documentation says about **[Strict Mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)**

Here's how to **[Disable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/15172069)** it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).