# when useRef is used as a counter shown below, Instead of adding one , its adding two times

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

When add name is clicked the idRef is incrementing 2 times instead of 1 time.
the output is shown below

```js
const { useRef, useState } = React;
function UseRefs() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const idRef = useRef(1);
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  const addName = () => {
    setNames((prevNames) => [
      ...prevNames,
      { id: idRef.current++, name: inputRef.current.value },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div >
        {names.map((name) => (
          <div key={name.id}>
            {name.id}. {name.name}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="m-3">
        <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
        <button  onClick={addName}> Add name </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<UseRefs />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

OUTPUT:

1 a, 3 ab, 5 ABC, 7 abcd

EXPECTED

1. a
2. ab
3. abc
4. abcd

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbBtr.png)

Comment: Your OUTPUT is the same as your EXPECTED, and the result of the code in your question matches both...

Comment: instead of 1 2 3 4 , I am getting 1 3 5 7

Comment: The code in your question does not produce such a thing, as you can see if you run the snippet.

Comment: yes, but in my localhost is showing  1 3 5 7 even after restarting the server

Comment: Edit the code in the question so that we can reproduce the problem too - we can't debug what we can't see

Comment: You have `StrictMode` locally which increases the ref value two times. The error does not occur here since there is no `StrictMode`, instead use a `state` for the count or just the `index` of the map function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because react is rendering the component UseRefs twice.

This is due to the <React.StrictMode> is enabled by default when creating
react app with npx create-react-app.

details are shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61897567/16958718