# A strange problem about updating useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code :

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function App() {
   let [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   let [num, setNum] = useState(0);

   useEffect(() => {
       setCount((pre) => {
           return pre + 1;
       });
       setNum(num + 1);
   }, []);

   return (
     <p>
         count:{count} num:{num}
     </p>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

The result is : count:2 num:1! why?

In theory, num and count should be synchronous, I don't know what happend!
In dev mode, useEffect's callback executed twice.

Comment: "In theory, num and count should be synchronous" -- setters are async according to React. Anyway, this works fine for me. I see 1, 1.

Comment: Checkout the values of `num` and `pre` and you'll see why. The `num` inside `useEffect` is in a closure that doesn't update because the dependencies doesn't include `num`. The `pre` on the other hand is called with the updated value, because this is how setting the state with a callback works.

Comment: Please have a look at this question that might help you understand what happens in your code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Comment: Yeah, definitely a strict mode thing. If you add `<React.StrictMode>` around `<App />` in the above example, there's the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

Comment: thanks guys！ i'll learn about theclosure about this!

Comment: i know why this rendering twice!  my doubt is why num and count are not synchronization!   setNum and setCount all executed twice!   in my opinion, they are all 2

Comment: @chichen The reason is that the callback in the `useEffect` is defined once, but executed twice. When *defined*, the value of `num` is `0`, so `num + 1` will always be equals to `1`, whatever the number of times it is *executed*. However, the `count` is updated using its previous value, in the updater function. This is why, when called twice, it gets incremented twice as well.

Comment: @Ori Drori is right!  The issue is caused by the closure.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of StricMode :

> Strict Mode only runs in development, which does not impede the production build. It logs extra warnings or errors and **invokes functions twice** to ensure that the expected results always occur

you may wonder why they have different values and you think that they should have the same, either 1 or 2

This is because when you update a state value with the function like you did for `count` :

```js
setCount((pre) => {
   return pre + 1;
});
```

This will make the state updates based on it previous values not based on its value in the last render 
 and this is why we use the function of `useState` so to have access to the previous value of the state before the next render and we can also update it again just before the component rerenders as it happend in this example

So here the second time useEffect runs (because of strictMode) `pre` is equal to `1` so the final value will be `2`.
However when you update your state this way :

```js
setNum(num + 1);
```

It will be updated based on `num` and `num` is still equal to 0 because the component didn't rerendered yet

Answer (score 0):

The prime reason behind this is [`StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects)

> StrictMode renders components twice (on dev but not production) in order to detect any problems with your code and warn you about them (which can be quite useful).

If you want to get rid of this, change

```
 ReactDOM.render(
     <React.StrictMode>
       {app}
     </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

to

```
  ReactDOM.render(
    {app}
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```