# Axios making double post request while loading page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, jwt

When I made this post request with postman it works fine but in this case my django server shows two requests are made and data is also logged twice. I am using jwt tokens if it is related somehow ...

```
  const controller = new AbortController();
    const [isLoading , setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const [userData , setUserData] = useState({
        name:"",
        username:"",
        email:""
    })

    const getData = () =>{
      axiosInstance.post("/api/detail/" , {
        signal:controller.signal
      })
      .then((data) =>{
        setUserData({
            name : data.data.name,
            username : data.data.username,
            email : data.data.email
          }
          )
          console.log(data) // this data is logged twice 
          setIsLoading(false)
      return controller.abort()

      }).catch((err)=>{
          console.log("error is" , err)
      })
      return controller.abort()
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        getData()
    } ,[])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why useEffect running twice and how to handle it well in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72238175/why-useeffect-running-twice-and-how-to-handle-it-well-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the StrictMode. Check your main file (index.js, main.js) and see if the component is wrapped like this:

```js
root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

For more details about that, you can see this answer: [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode/61897567#61897567)

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` is called twice in the development mode and will only run once on production if strict mode is enabled.

You shouldn't try to use those technics with `useRef` and `if` statements in `useEffect` to make it fire once, or remove `StrictMode` because react intentionally remounts your components in development to help you find bugs and because of that use effect is called twice. Read here for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238236/12083049

I would highly recommend using a data-fetching library like [react-query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/) or [swr](https://github.com/vercel/swr) to work with API.

swr example:

```js
import useSWR from 'swr'
 
function Profile() {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR('/api/user', fetcher)
 
  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
  if (isLoading) return <div>loading...</div>
  return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
```