# Why my useEffect (ComponentDidMount) lifecycle triggers twice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I am using `@preact/signals-react` to integrate my `react` project.

I have an issue that need a fix.

P.S I found that if I removed the `import { signal } from '@preact/signals-react'`, thats work for me. I want to use `@preact/signals-react` tools.

My Environment

1. React v16.8.6
2. @preact/signals-react v1.2.2

My Code

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { signal } from '@preact/signals-react';

const Scenes = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ComponentDidMount'); // Trigger Twice !!
    }, []);

    return <div>Hello</div>;
}

export default Scenes;
```

Comment: What did you pass as the dependency array?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode  Can this  solve your problem?

Comment: Sor, I missed the empty array, but seems not work, still triggers twice. and I edited the post detail.

Answer (score 2):

StrictMode is a development tool that renders components twice, with the purpose of detecting any issues with your code and alerting you about them. This feature is particularly useful during development.

If you are using StrictMode in your application but cannot remember explicitly enabling it, it is likely because you used a tool like create-react-app to set up your application, which automatically enables StrictMode by default.

you might find that your main app is wrapped by <React.StrictMode> in your index.js file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
 <React.StrictMode>
   {app}
 </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root'))
```

you can remove the strict mode by

```
ReactDOM.render(
    {app}
document.getElementById('root'));
```

*Strict mode is not enabled in production*

Comment: I pretty sure I have not use the StrictMode since my react version is v16.x

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use dependency array, `useEffect` will run in every render.
if you want to render once keep dependency array empty.

```
  useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ComponentDidMount');
  }, []);
```

Comment: Yea, I updated the post detail, found that some tricky point

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand useEffect properly, it takes two arguments.

First one is a callback function and other one is dependency array. Whatever you put in the dependency array is the checkbox to check when to render it again.

Learn more here - https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-dependencies-in-useeffect-7afd4df37c96?gi=41a7917490c8