# Does React re-render more than once per onClick Event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, render

Im reading the learning react documentation on the react website and in the Queueing A Series of State Updates section there is a sentence that reads
"the UI won't be updated until after your event handles, and any code in it, completes." From this I get the impression that there can only be one render
per onClick event but in running the following component it seems the component re-renders twice. Once when adding to the pending state and another when decrementing the pending state and incrementing state inside the setTimeout function.

```
function RequestTracker() {
  const [pending, setPending] = useState(0);
  const [completed, setCompleted] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("MyComponent rendered!");
  });

  function handleClick() {
    setPending((p) => p + 1);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setCompleted((c) => c + 1);
      setPending((p) => p - 1);
    }, 3000);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Pending: {pending}</h3>
      <h3>Completed: {completed}</h3>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Buy</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Doesn't this contradict the statement that React only renders the UI *after* the event handler completes all code in it?

Using the useEffect there is indeed more than one render per click. How should I think about
how React queues and executes re-renders. Thank you!

Comment: This is likely because of React's strict mode rendering components twice in development (but not production). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Comment: Worth noting that renders are driven by changes in state which _may_ occur as the result of an event. An event doesn't cause a render by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the UI won't be updated until after your event handles, and any code in it, completes.

This statement is true.  Your `handleClick` function is completing before the component re-renders.

> but in running the following component it seems the component re-renders twice

That's to be expected in this case.  Look closely at what the code is doing:

```
function handleClick() {
  setPending((p) => p + 1);
  setTimeout(() => {
    setCompleted((c) => c + 1);
    setPending((p) => p - 1);
  }, 3000);
}
```

What does the function `handleClick` do?  Exactly two things:

1. Call `setPending` to queue a state update.
2. Call `setTimeout` to schedule some function to execute at some later time.

Then it's done.  The function has run to completion, performed all of its tasks, and the framework now sees that a state update has been queued and the framework re-renders the component with the new state.

Then, *at some later time*, this happens:

```
setCompleted((c) => c + 1);
setPending((p) => p - 1);
```

Which does exactly two things:

1. Call `setCompleted` to queue a state update.
2. Call `setPending` to queue a state update.

Once this is done, this operation has completed its logic.  The React framework then sees that there are state updates, processes them, and re-renders the component accordingly.

---

Overall it seems that your confusion is from an expectation that `setTimeout` is a blocking operation.  It isn't.  It schedules logic to happen at some later time, and then frees up the JavaScript engine to continue processing.

Comment: Wow great answer thank you! Follow up question: Does any rendering logic change if I make my handleClick function this,  
async function handleClick() {
    setPending(pending + 1);
    await delay(3000);
    setPending(pending - 1);
    setCompleted(completed + 1);
  }
where 
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });

Comment: @qhuboo: Test it and observe the result.  But in that test be aware that while `handleClick` may internally `await` an operation, the framework is not going to `await` the call to `handleClick`.  So I would suspect that you still may observe two renders, since nothing is blocking.

Comment: Same number of renders as the previous code. I should probably dig into the internals. Thank you!