# Vite + React: My post route is hitting multiple times within a useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, spotify

I am implementing the spotify api into my app however as shown in the picture below the post route gets hit 2-4 times and consstantly overwrites all the data leading to errors.

Repo(in case you need it): https://github.com/kankanrr/post-route

[post route hitting multiple times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/psdSS.png)

```
const client_id = ""; // Your client id
  const client_secret = ""; // Your secret
  const redirect_uri = "http://localhost:3000/callback";

  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState("");
  const [refreshToken, setRefreshToken] = useState("");
  const [expiresIn, setExpiresIn] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const authParams = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization:
          "Basic " +
          new Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString("base64"),
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "authorization_code",
        redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
        code: code,
      }),
    };
    const refreshParams = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Authorization:
          "Basic " +
          new Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString("base64"),
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        grant_type: "refresh_token",
        refresh_token: refreshToken,
        client_id: client_id,
      }),
    };
    fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", authParams)
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        if (!accessToken) {
          setAccessToken(data.access_token);
        }
        setRefreshToken(data.refresh_token);
        setExpiresIn(data.expires_in);
        if (!expiresIn) {
          fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", refreshParams)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
              setExpiresIn(data.expires_in);
              setAccessToken(data.access_token);
            });
        }

        console.log(data.access_token);
        // if (accessToken) return console.log("access toke +> " + accessToken);
        // else window.history.pushState({}, null, "/");
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.sendStatus(400);
      });
  }, []);
```

I only want this to run once so my tokens dont get overwritten. This useEffect was originally two seperate useEffects, but i merged into one to see if it would fix the problem. I tried removing react strict mode that just completely broke the app. I tried async rqs within the useeffect. Im honestly not sure what the problem is here and why its posting mulltiple times and overwriting my token data.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment so I will put this here.

If you are running the application in dev mode with React.StrictMode, then any re-render will trigger twice. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode) for more information.

Try running the application in preview mode with: `vite preview` and check if the problem carries over to the build.

Answer (score 0):

Add accessToken and refreshToken inside dependency array of useEffect hook.

Comment: i had it in before and still the error persisted 

Screenshot: https://files.catbox.moe/j358pn.png