# Need to make a call to one api only once when the page is loaded and once when the same page is unloaded (e.g. user switch to other page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to make a "single" call to one API when particular page is loaded (on Load)
and later when user navigate to some other page then I want to make another call (on un load) using react component. I have created below component for the same but
it hits onload call twice and on unload call single without even unloading the page.

Can some one help to find out the issue.

```
function ActivityTracker() {
  // Function to make the API call on page load
  const onPageLoad = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      // Handle the data as needed
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error on page load:', error);
    }
  };

  // Function to make the API call on page unload
  const onPageUnload = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      // Handle the data as needed
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error on page unload:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    onPageLoad();
  }, []);

  return <div>Your page content goes here</div>;
}

export default ActivityTracker;
```

project link on stackblitz ->  https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-b32vmo?file=src%2FActivityTracker.js,src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the following changes to achieve what you are looking for:

1. Return onPageUnload in the `useEffect` callback

```
useEffect(() => {
    onPageLoad();
    return onPageUnload;
}, []);
```

This will call the `onPageUnload` function when the component is unloaded. This is the clean up function that is automatically called by `useEffect` - [docs here](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect).

2. Remove the `<StrictMode></StrictMode>` from your index.js. Wrapping your code with `StrictMode` calls it twice on dev server. It will be called only once on production. More details in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the correct way to do this one. I am using "beforeunload" event with "window.addEventListener" in useEffect. Below is the code which is working as expected.

```
useEffect(() => {
onPageLoad();
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', onPageUnload);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', onPageUnload);
};
}, []);
```

[Working code here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-user-activity-tracker)

Answer (score -1):

use this code :

```
     function ActivityTracker() {
 // Function to make the API call on page load
   const [res, setRes] = React.useState([]);

   // Function to make the API call on page unload
    const onPageUnload = async () => {
    try {
     const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
     // Handle the data as needed
    } catch (error) {
     console.error('Error on page unload:', error);
   }
   };

useEffect(() => {
const onPageLoad = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
    );
    setRes(response.json());
    // Handle the data as needed
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error on page load:', error);
  }
};
  onPageLoad();
 }, [setRes]);
 }

export default ActivityTracker;
```

its because StrictMode tag in your index.js file remove this tag the Api going to call once and for calling api after load the page you can use a timer set timer for 30 sec then after 30 sec you can call Api again automatically

Comment: thanks for psosting. I tried to integrate it in same stackblitz but its calling onload api twice and no call being made on page unload.

Comment: its because   <StrictMode> in your index.js file remove this tag the Api going to call once and for calling api after load the page you can use a timer set timer for 30 sec then after 30 sec you can call Api again automatically