# ReactJS: Why page is accessed multiple times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express

I have below code. I am accessing /profile page. In the process /profile is accessed by 6 times. It sends 6 times POST request to back end. After using hook useEffect, I see still it access the /profile page 6 times, however now it sends POST request two times to backend.

Is this behaviour normal? Whats wrong here?

```
import react, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Profile = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(null);
    let user = localStorage.getItem('user');
    
    console.log('Local storage user = ' + user);

    const data = {user: user};
    const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

    useEffect ( () => {
        try {
            axios
            .post('/profile', data, {headers: headers})
            .then(function (res) {
                console.log("Got 200 for /profile request");
                let obj = JSON.parse(res.data);
                setFirstName(obj.firstname);
                setLastName(obj.lastname);
            })
        }catch (err) {
            console.log("Error:" + err.message);
        };
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className="medium-text">
            <div className="center">
                <h2>User profile data</h2>
                {firstName && <div>First name: {firstName}</div>}
                {lastName && <div>Last name: {lastName}</div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 0):

logic is wrong, maybe you can do like this

```js
import react, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Profile = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState(null);
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState(null);

    async fetchProfile() {
       const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
       await axios.post('/profile', {user}, {
           headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/json'
           }
       }).then(function (res) {
          console.log("Got 200 for /profile request");
          let obj = JSON.parse(res.data);
          setFirstName(obj.firstname);
          setLastName(obj.lastname);
        })
    }

    useEffect ( () => {
       fetchProfile()
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div className="medium-text">
            <div className="center">
                <h2>User profile data</h2>
                {firstName && <div>First name: {firstName}</div>}
                {lastName && <div>Last name: {lastName}</div>}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Comment: Getting build error at async fetchProfile() {, error is like "SyntaxError: Profile.js: Missing semicolon. (8:9)"

Comment: I modified the line to "const fetchProfile = async () => {", to avoid build error. With this I see page is accessed 4 times and POST is sent to backend two times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure reactStrictMode is enabled

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, the current code runs useEffect two times?

Is reactStrictMode enabled? If so, everything will render two times **on the dev server (not on prod)**. This would be the normal behavior.

See [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)