# React loop inside loop shows multiple console.logs

Tags: reactjs

I have a couple of elements (rows) inside a table, those rows have 2 classes (ampFilter and prod-{some_product} (depending on what product it is)).

Now what I am trying to do is get all elements with a specific class (ampFilter), which works (see example before).

I also have a couple of checkboxes, each with a value of a product.

When I check 2 checkboxes, the filterType gets filled with an array of those values.

Now when I click a button, I want to loop through the elements and check if they contain the prod-.. class(es), if not hide those rows (only showing the rows that have the prod-.. class(es)).

I currently check with a console.log what the values are, but it gets shown 8 times (2x 4 of the elements)

```
const filterHandler = () => {
    const filterClass = document.querySelectorAll(".ampFilter"); // I have 4 rows with this class
    filterClass.forEach((clss) => {
        console.log("clss", clss); // this shows 4 items
        filterTypes.forEach((type) => {
            console.log("type", type);  // this shows 8 times the type console
            // if (!clss.classList.contains(type)) {
            //     clss.classList.add("hidden");
            // } else {
            //     clss.classList.remove("hidden");
            // }
        });
    });
};
```

Here is a small example: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/h67y36?migrateFrom=rqkkx6

**Little bit more explaining**
The issue I have, is that when I uncomment the classList part. And I check both the checkboxes in the example. All the rows with those "prod-.." classes get the hidden class, except the YT product. While also the SB product should not have the hidden class.

Comment: can you clarify what you are expecting to happen? Can you also include a sample of the HTML that's relevant.

Comment: Is the component simply double-rendering in strict mode for development?  Is this causing an actual problem, or just an unexpected but otherwise harmless result?  Why are you directly manipulating the DOM in the first place if this is intended to be used in React?  Can you update this to a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing?

Comment: `querySelectorAll` in React context? You're going the wrong way m8

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode?

Comment: @udarts: And can you clarify what specific problem you are observing in that example?  When you debug, which specific operation produces an unexpected result?  What was that result?  What were the values used?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: I have removed the strictmode from the example, seems to look ok, but on the code (on my laptop), I still see it multiple times, even-though it is the same code (without the strictmode)

Comment: @David I added some extra explaining and uncommented the example with the classList part

Comment: @udarts: It sounds like the problem you're *trying* to describe is that the logic within your loop isn't what you expect.  Though if you step through that logic line by line, you'll see it's exactly what was written.  Each iteration of each loop is essentially over-writing the effects of the previous one.  This is a good opportunity for you to take a step back and not use manual DOM manipulation in React in the first place.  Instead of messing with element classes directly, remove that part and in your JSX you can conditionally include/exclude the `hidden` class based on state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All the rows with those "prod-.." classes get the hidden class, except the YT product. While also the SB product should not have the hidden class.

Now we're getting to the actual problem.  It's not React, not logging to the console, none of that.  Consider the logic being used here:

```
filterClass.forEach((clss) => {
  // looping through every target element
  filterTypes.forEach((type) => {
    // looping through every filter type
    if (!clss.classList.contains(type)) {
      clss.classList.add("hidden");
    } else {
      clss.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
  });
});
```

So what happens when you have both the "SB" and the "YT" filters selected?  When the outer loop is on the "SB" element and the inner loop iterates over the filters, if "YT" was selected second then that last iteration of the inner loop is going to hide the "prod-sb" element, because the class list of that element doesn't contain "prod-yt".

Take a step back.

Instead of showing/hiding in the loop, another approach would be to initially hide *everything* and then *conditionally show* in the loop.  Which would turn out to be simpler anyway.  First, apply "hidden" to all target elements, then loop over the filter types and remove "hidden" from any matching elements for each filter.

But, take a *bigger* step back.

This is React.  Why are you manually manipulating the DOM in the first place?  These events should just update state, and state should be used in the rendering to conditionally show/hide elements.

To that end, you don't even need the button in the first place.  The button and its handler function can just be removed.  You're already updating the state of the filter when using the checkboxes.  All you need to do is use that state in your rendering.  For example:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr className={`ampFilter prod-sb ${(filterTypes.includes("prod-sb") ? "" : "hidden")}`}>
      <td>SB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className={`ampFilter prod-td ${(filterTypes.includes("prod-td") ? "" : "hidden")}`}>
      <td>TD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className={`ampFilter prod-lb ${(filterTypes.includes("prod-lb") ? "" : "hidden")}`}>
      <td>LB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr className={`ampFilter prod-yt ${(filterTypes.includes("prod-yt") ? "" : "hidden")}`}>
      <td>YT</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

You *could* re-add the button if you want that specific user experience.  In that case I suppose you'd create a second state value which conditionally determines if the filter should be applied or not (a simple boolean value) and the button would just update that state, and that boolean value could be used in the ternary conditions above.  But that sounds a bit clunky to be honest, I don't think the button is needed here.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. The reason why I wanted a button is to start the filter of the rows after the button click and not when the checkbox(es) are checked.