# Next.js Function Running Twice

Tags: reactjs, function, next.js, types, jsx

My `addToCart` function is running twice on click.

//Function

```
const addToCart = useCallback(() => {
    if (produto && cartItems) {
      setCartItems((prev: LocalStorageItem[]) => {
        if (!Array.isArray(prev)) {
          return [
            {
              productId: produto.id,
              color: variavelAtual.color,
              quantity: quantidade,
            },
          ];
        }

        const itemExists = cartItems?.find(
          (item) => item.productId === produto.id
        );
        if (!itemExists || itemExists === undefined) {
          return [
            ...prev,
            {
              productId: produto.id,
              color: variavelAtual.color,
              quantity: quantidade,
            },
          ];
        } else {
          console.log(quantidade);
          console.log(itemExists.quantity);
          changeCartItemQuantity(
            produto.id,
            variavelAtual.color,
            itemExists.quantity + quantidade
          );
          return cartItems;
        }
      });
      toast.success("Produto Adicionado Com Sucesso");
      router.push("/cart");
      setIsAdded(true);
    }
  }, [
    cartItems,
    changeCartItemQuantity,
    produto,
    quantidade,
    router,
    setCartItems,
    variavelAtual.color,
  ]);
```

//Change Quantity Function

```
function changeCartItemQuantity(
    productId: string,
    color: string,
    quantity: number
  ) {
    if (cartItems) {
      const newCartItem = cartItems.find(
        (item) => item.productId === productId && item.color === color
      );
      const newCartItemIndex = cartItems.findIndex(
        (item) => item.productId === productId && item.color === color
      );

      if (newCartItem) {
        newCartItem.quantity = quantity;

        const newCartItems = cartItems.map((item, index) =>
          index === newCartItemIndex ? newCartItem : item
        );

        setCartItems(newCartItems);
      }
    }
  }
```

//Only Component that calls it

```
"use client";
import CheckCircleRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/CheckCircleRounded";
import DangerousRoundedIcon from "@mui/icons-material/DangerousRounded";

interface ProductButton {
  isAdded: boolean;
  selling: boolean;
  stock: number;
  cartQuantity: number;
  addToCart: () => void;
}

export default function ProductButton({
  isAdded,
  selling,
  stock,
  cartQuantity,
  addToCart,
}: ProductButton) {
  if (cartQuantity === stock || cartQuantity > stock) {
    if (stock === 0) {
      return <div></div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <DangerousRoundedIcon
              className="text-error mr-4"
              fontSize="large"
            />
            <p className="text-lg"> Limite de Estoque Atingido no Carrinho</p>
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
  } else if (stock > 0 && selling) {
    return (
      <>
        {!isAdded ? (
          <button
            onClick={addToCart}
            className="bg-base-content text-base-100 rounded-md h-[3rem] w-full hover:bg-primary duration-300"
          >
            Adicionar ao Carrinho
          </button>
        ) : (
          <div className="flex items-center">
            <CheckCircleRoundedIcon
              className="text-success mr-4"
              fontSize="large"
            />
            <p className="text-lg"> Produto Adicionado ao Carrinho</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </>
    );
  } else if (!selling) {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <DangerousRoundedIcon className="text-error mr-4" fontSize="large" />{" "}
          <p className="text-lg"> Produto Não está À Venda</p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <DangerousRoundedIcon className="text-error mr-4" fontSize="large" />{" "}
          <p className="text-lg"> Produto Fora de Estoque</p>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

It only happens with Strict Mode activated, but why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

Comment: Thanks friend, I know this happens because of Strict Mode, but I just want to know why in this case. In most cases it happens on `useEffects`, mainly because of a miss use of a `setTimeout` or not creating a cleanup function. But in this case, I don't see why it's having this side effect, and that's what I really want to understand. Most people just tell me to disable it, but it helps a lot to detect Memory Leaks and miss using of API Calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those with the same problem as me.

It's a little confusing what was happening but try to follow.

I was changing the State, using the `changeCartItemQuantity`, inside of a `setState` function, then returning the new `cartItems` that were already updated.

I don't understand why it made the function runs twice, but just make it simple and everything will be alright, just don't try to make complex functions inside `setStates`

Or just remove the Strict Mode, but I don't recommend