# How can I stop infinite loop and multi call of api in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I create a component which have to call 3 api.

The issue is with one of the call I have to do a filter on the 2 others one but if I do this I have an infinite loop because I set so the component is re-render

```
const component = ({}) => {
    const [selectedDataFromTabA, setSelectedDataFromTabA] = React.useState(null)
    const [selectedDataFromTabB, setSelectedDataFromTabB] = React.useState(null)

    const { data, loading, error} = useFetch(getData())
    const { data: dataTabA, loading: loadingTabA, error: errorTabA} = useFetch(getDataTabA())
    const { data: dataTabB, loading: loadingTabB, error: errorTabB} = useFetch(getDataTabB())

    if (loading|| loadingTabA|| loadingTabB)
        return "loading"

    if (error|| errorTabA|| errorTabB)
        return 'eror'
    
    setSelectedDataFromTabA(dataTabA.filter(x => x.IdTabA == data[0].IdTabA ))
    setSelectedDataFromTabB(dataTabB.filter(x => x.IdTabB == data[0].IdTabB ))

    return <div>NULL</div>
}
```

The problem is if I put my sets in **useEffect** it will call 2 or 3 times my api.
So how can I avoid infinite loop and multi calls on api.

```
function useFetch(serviceFunctionApiCall) {
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = React.useState(false)
    const [data, setData] = React.useState(null)
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const init = async () => {
            var response = await serviceFunctionApiCall
            if (response.status != 200) {
                setError(true)
            } else {
                setData(response.data)
            }
            setLoading(false)
        }

        init()
    }, [])
    return {
        loading,
        error,
        data,
        setData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should **never** call a setter directly inside the body of the component, else each time your component will be rerenderd the setter will be called causing a rerender and so here is your infinite loop.

A change of state should only occurred inside of a hook or be triggered by an interaction.

In your case, you want to set `selectedDataFromTabA` if `data` or `dataTabA` is changed, and same for `selectedDataFromTabB`. So you should put your updates in some useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
 if(data && dataTabA) {
   setSelectedDataFromTabA(dataTabA.filter(x => x.IdTabA == data[0].IdTabA ))
 }
}, [data, dataTabA)

useEffect(() => {
 if(data && dataTabB) {
   setSelectedDataFromTabB(dataTabB.filter(x => x.IdTabB == data[0].IdTabB ))
 }
}, [data, dataTabB)
```

Comment: `useMemo()` would be a better fit given the context. The only reason to use a state is if OP wants to change the collection after it's being loaded. `const selectedDataFromTabA = useMemo(() => data && dataTabA && dataTabA.filter(x => x.IdTabA == data[0].IdTabA), [data, dataTabA])`

Comment: Indeed, but in that case we should also ask ourselves if it is needed to memoize those values, and so just creating the variable in the body of the component should be enough. Not sure i should add it in the answer though as they might have their own reason to use a state here

Comment: It was the second part of my question, so when I put the setter in useeffect it will call multiple times my api because it rerender the component. To avoid that I have to put the api call in parent ? or there is an other solution ?

And yeah I have to use a setter because the data will change with user interaction.

Comment: Where does the `useFetch` hook comes from ?

Comment: I create my own useFetch, i updated my question.

Comment: Maybe the problem comes from this hook, because a well designed hook shouldn't be reexecuted without reason on rerender :/ can you add its implementation on your question ?

Comment: @user10863293 The component should only call the API once for `getData()`, once for `getDataTabA()`, and once for `getDataTabB()`. It might be called twice depending on the implementation of `useFetch()` in combination with `<React.StrictMode>`, though this issue should not occur in production. See: [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode). (1/2)

Comment: my bad it doesn't call it multiple times i'm stupied sorry ^^'. I try to add a console.log in my response and it's ok

Comment: Alternatively React might unmount/mount your component if the JSX position changes. Which could cause multiple API calls. You could solve this by providing you component with a key to help React identify it as the same component, preventing an unmount/mount cycle. `<YourComponent key="unique-identifier">` (2/2)

Comment: If it doesn't call the api on rerender can you update your question so it only contains the initial problem ?