# React useEffect dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from "react";

export default function TestComponent(){
    const [booValue, setBoolValue] = React.useState(false)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setBoolValue(!booValue);
    },[])
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('booValue is', booValue)
    },[booValue])

    return (
        <></>
    )
}
```

What to do not to print twice. **Its not in StrictMode**

```
boolValue is false
boolValue is true
```

tried default value as undefined, i assume that `useEffect` triggers on setting default values. tried with null values too.

Comment: React always renders twice on dev mode. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode

Comment: remove the first `useEffect` and set the initial value to `true` instead of `false`. But I don't really understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My React Component is rendering twice because of Strict Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61254372/my-react-component-is-rendering-twice-because-of-strict-mode)

Comment: @Kulakesh, when you call `setBoolValue(!booValue);` you're causing the component to render again with a new value for `booValue`. 2 renders with different `booValue`s = 2 logs. Are you trying to not have 2 renders, or keep the 2 renders but skip logging on the second one?